# How to make and handle POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, clojure

I have a Clojure service:

```
(ns cowl.server
  (:use compojure.core)

  (:require [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [ring.middleware.params :as params]
            [ring.middleware.json :as wrap-json]
            [ring.util.response :refer [response]]
            [clojure.data.json :as json]
            [cowl.settings :as settings]
            [cowl.db :as db]))

(defn set-as-readed [body]

  (println body)
  (db/set-as-readed settings/db (:link body))
  (str "ok"))

(defroutes main-routes
  (POST "/api/news/as-read" { body :body } (set-as-readed body)))

(def app
  (-> main-routes
      wrap-json/wrap-json-response
      (wrap-json/wrap-json-body { :keywords? true })))
```

If I test it using REST client - it works fine:

[image]

If I use it from jQuery I have an error:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/news/as-read',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify( { link: news.link } ),
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
```

Here is logs from server:

```
{:link http://www.linux.org.ru/news/internet/12919692}
#object[org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP 0x11724c56 HttpInputOverHTTP@11724c56]
```

First message from REST client, second from my AJAX jQuery request ?

Where did I make an error? The REST client works fine. So I can propose that the server is correct. Why the server can not parse the request from jQuery ?

**Update:** I can solve problem by:

```
(json/read-str (slurp body)
```

on the server side.  In this case I can work with my jQuery request, but can not parse REST Client request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring JSON middleware uses the `Content-Type` header to detect and parse JSON payloads. Most likely the request from jQuery is either omitting this header, or using a default value, so the request body shows up to your handler as a raw text stream.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) it looks like the `dataType` tells jQuery what data type you're expecting in the *response*. It looks like you want to be setting the `contentType` parameter to `"application/json"`.

Answer (score 1):

You must to say to requester you are sending text or json by changing your header response:

```
(-> (ring-resp/response (str "Ok"))
    (ring-resp/header ("Content-Type" "text/plain"))) 
    ;; or application/json if convenient
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/news/as-read',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    link: news.link
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: The same problem.